# Android - Cant Get the parsed JSON values

Tags: android, json

main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    String param;

    String Result;
    TextView tv1,tv2;

    String TAG = "myApp";

    String strParsedValue = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        postData(param);
        try {
            parseJSON();

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Mapping the text view

```
    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
}

public void postData(final String param) {

    RequestQueue rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    StringRequest postReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            "http://api.docx.json",
            new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    // tv.setText(response); // We set the response data in
                    // the TextView
                /*  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Response" + response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    System.out.println("Error [" + error + "]");

                }
            }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

            params.put("key", "value);
            params.put("cal", "com");
            params.put("a", "x");

            return params;
        }
    };

    rq.add(postReq);
}

private void parseJSON() throws JSONException {

    String json = "";
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
    JSONArray columns = jsonObject.getJSONArray("columns");
    String column0 = columns.getString(0);
    String column1 = columns.getString(1);
    JSONArray rowsWrapper = jsonObject.getJSONArray("rows");
    JSONArray rows = rowsWrapper.getJSONArray(0);
    int row0 = rows.getInt(0);
    String row1 = rows.getString(1);

    Log.d("values-", "column0 " + column0 + " column1 " + column1+ " row0 " + row0 + " row1 " + row1);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+columns, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Key value pair has been used

{
    "columns": [
        "comp",
        "Com Description"
    ],
    "rows": [
        [
            20614,
            "RAX"
        ]
    ]
}

Above Is the json

Answer (score 0):

Is a lot easier if you model a POJO like this:

```
public class MyPOJO {

    private String[] columns;

    private String[][] rows;

    public String[] getColumns() {
        return columns;
    }

    public void setColumns(String[] columns) {
        this.columns = columns;
    }

    public String[][] getRows() {
        return rows;
    }

    public void setRows(String[][] rows) {
        this.rows = rows;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ClassPojo [columns = " + columns + ", rows = " + rows + "]";
    }
}
```

And then you do this:

```
Gson gson=new Gson();
MyPOJO p = gson.fromJson(YOUR_JSON_STRING, MyPOJO.class);
```